# Can single remote git branch has multiple HEADs?

Tags: git, github, branch

I know this question might sounds weird but after reading git documentation and code I am currently working with - I am little confused.
The question is: Is it possible to have two HEADs for single branch in git?

As far as I know HEAD is a pointer which tells us what is a base commit to create next one for particular branch. 
 I've checked Github / Gitlab documentation and no mention about such possibility.

My weird question is because code I'm currently working on expect `List<BranchHead>` for single `Branch` polled with Rest API from Github.
If there is any rare but possible situation to achieve that - I would be really appreciated to get know.

Comment: I think you've already answered your question by explaining what a HEAD pointer is. Why that is in a List<> is anyone's guess but that is of course something that can be done with a single one of anything, including HEAD pointers.

Comment: First some terms: the head of a branch (the topmost commit of a branch) is not the same as `HEAD` (which, in a remote repository, means "the default branch"). To answer your question: no, a single branch has a single head. You would have to read the code to see if there is a reason why you have a `List<BranchHead>` at that place -- without seeing the code, it will be difficult to give an actual answer to that, a blind guess could be: the base API handles `List<BranchHead>`, so the calling code kept that ?

Comment: @LeGEC You are right. Whole code is prepared to handle List<> but it's inefficient and makes code worse to read. 
Just before I change it to handle single object I wanted to make research aren't there any edge cases.